# Having trouble solo mining

Tags: solo-mining, error, guiminer

I mine for fun. Please no responses saying "You really shouldn't mine on that computer. At all. Forget mining exists."

Whenever I try to mine using the instructions given in the README of the GUIMiner, it gives me an error as soon as the bitcoin.exe launches as a server.

Here's the error:

Invalid -rpcallowip subnet specification: *. Valid are a single IP (e.g. 1.2.3.4), a network/netmask (e.g. 1.2.3.4/255.255.255.0) or a network/CIDR (e.g. 1.2.3.4/24).

Comment: So, what value did you specify for `-rpcallowip`? Does it match one of the listed valid patterns?

Comment: Shouldn't it be localhost?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing it to `rpcallowip=192.168.0.0/24`. Wildcard support was removed from `bitcoind`, more on reasoning here:

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/4102

`rpcallowip=192.168.0.0/24`is [CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) notation that is functionally the same as `192.168.1.*`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What worked for me was opening username/%appdata%/roaming/bitcoin. Then opened bitcoin.config with notepad. I changed rpcallowip=192.168.0.* to rpcallowip=192.168.0.1/24

I'm still very new to all this. This might not be your problem, but that's what I did to remove that error.